# How do I transform a values to a columns and put values from other column into these columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this following dataframe from pandas:

```
code_module code_presentation   id_student  date_cat    sum_click
AAA         2013J               11391       -9~-1       98
AAA         2013J               11391       0~9         203
AAA         2013J               11391       10~19       36
AAA         2013J               11391       20~29       100
AAA         2013J               11391       30~39       82
BBB         2013J               11391       0~9         10
AAA         2013J               20394       <-20        100
```

Now I want to achieve something like the following:

```
code_module code_presentation   id_student  <-20     -19~-10     -9~-1       0~9      10~19     20~29    30~39     ......
AAA         2013J               11391       0        0           98          203      36        100      82        ......
BBB         2013J               11391       0        0           0           10       0         0        82        ......
AAA         2013J               20394       100      0           0           0        0         0        82        ......
```

Note that I have several date_cat values demonstrated below

```
["<-20", "-19~-10", "-9~-1", "0~9", "10~19", "20~29", "30~39", "40~49", "50~59", "60~69", "70~79", "80~89","90~99","100~109","110~119","120~129","130~139","140~149","150~159","160~169","170~179", "180~189","190~199","200~209","210~219","220~229","230~239","240~249","250~259","260~269"]
```

They are all going to be columns with some sum_click value. Only the rows with the same code_module, code_presentation, and id_student can go to the same row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `.pivot()`:

```
print(
    df.pivot(
        index=["code_module", "code_presentation", "id_student"],
        columns="date_cat",
        values="sum_click",
    )
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
    .reset_index()
)
```

Prints:

```
date_cat code_module code_presentation  id_student  -9~-1  0~9  10~19  20~29  30~39  <-20
0                AAA             2013J       11391     98  203     36    100     82     0
1                AAA             2013J       20394      0    0      0      0      0   100
2                BBB             2013J       11391      0   10      0      0      0     0
```